# match() выдаёт null при использовании значения переменной в регулярном выражении

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код:

```
var $c1_tag = '<ul class="class1 class2 class3 class4" id="id1" attr_name1="attr_value1"><li class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2"><span class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2">инфа</span></li></ul>';    
var $tag = "span"; //значение получается динамически
console.log($c1_tag.match(/<$tag.*?><\/$tag>/ig));
```

Хочу получить `<span class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2">инфа</span>`.

На выходе `null`. В чем проблема?

Comment: Нельзя в литеральной форме использовать переменную. Используйте конструктор `RegExp`. `$c1_tag.match(RegExp("<"+$tag+"\\b[^<]*>[^<]*</"+$tag+">", "ig")`. А еще лучше использовать JQuery для получения текстов в HTML-тегах.

Comment: он определен в коде, просто не хотел писать слишком длинный код. Результат переменной я написал в комментарии

Comment: +stribizhev а как мне быть тогда, если нужно взять из строки необходимое значение, что-то типо этого? `<span class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2">инфа</span>`

Comment: @Regent он у меня динамично создается, каждый раз по разному

Comment: в данном случаи это span

Comment: @stribizhev Спасибо большое, напишите ваш ответ, отдельным. Я отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут есть такой момент: нельзя в литеральной форме использовать переменную. В "динамическом" регулярном выражении необходимо использовать конструктор `RegExp`.

См. справку по этому методу в [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> Литеральная запись обеспечивает компиляцию регулярного выражения при вычислении выражения. Используйте литеральную запись если регулярное выражение будет неизменным. Например, если вы используете литеральную запись для конструирования регулярного выражения, используемого в цикле, регулярное выражение не будет перекомпилироваться на каждой итерации.

Я также исправил регулярное выражение, добавил `[^<]*` в середине и `\b`, чтобы при поиске `a` не нашло `area`.

```js
var $txt = '<ul class="class1 class2 class3 class4" id="id1" attr_name1="attr_value1"><li class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2"><span class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2">инфа</span></li></ul>';
var $tag = "span";
alert($txt.match(RegExp("<" + $tag + "\\b[^<]*>[^<]*</" + $tag + ">", "ig")));
```

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО**

Всё-таки лучше всего при работе с HTML пользоваться DOM. Предлагаю вариант для JavaScript без использования jQuery:

```js
var $tag = "span";
var $txt = '<ul class="class1 class2 class3 class4" id="id1" attr_name1="attr_value1"><li class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2"><span class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2">инфа</span></li></ul>';

var $el = document.createElement( 'html' );
$el.innerHTML = $txt;
var $arr = [];
[].forEach.call($el.getElementsByTagName($tag), function(v,i,a) {
    if (v.id == "id2") {
  $arr.push(v.outerHTML);
    }
});
console.log($arr);
```

И ещё один пример в jQuery:

```js
var $tag = "span";
var $txt = '<ul class="class1 class2 class3 class4" id="id1" attr_name1="attr_value1"><li class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2"><span class="class2" id="id2" attr_name2="attr_value2">инфа</span></li></ul>';
var nel = $('<div></div>' );
nel.html($txt);
console.log($($tag +'#id2', nel)[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А HTML у Вас как строка или просто код документа в браузере? Может, лучше будет использовать JQuery?

Comment: код в виде строки